# Is there a way to print multiple nodes on one paper using javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, printing, nodes

I can successfully print table on paper, but if I want to print also for example `label` above that table on the same paper, how to achieve that?
This is my code for printing:

```
private void print(Node node) {
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();                
    Scale scale = new Scale(scaleX, 1);
    node.getTransforms().add(scale);

    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(node.getScene().getWindow())) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, node);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }

    node.getTransforms().remove(scale);
}
```

I call `print` method in button like this:

```
printButton.setOnAction(e -> print(table));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your nodes into a container like a Pane and then print this pane. The pane is a Node itself.

Comment: I thought about it, but software architecture is such a mess :(